# I want to search files and folder in directories and sub directories php

Tags: php

I want to search files and folders in directory or its all sub-directories.

I'm using this code:

```
  <?php
    $a = new RegexIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('files')
    ),
    '/Desi Indian/',
    RegexIterator::MATCH
   );

   foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "$v\n"; //$v will be the filename
   }
?>
```

But, the problem is, like a file name is 'Wayne' and if search string is 'wayne', then it doesn't show any search result. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, the problem is , Like a file name is 'Wayne' and if search string
>   is 'wayne', then it will not show any search results.

This sounds like a question of searching case insensitive. Regular expressions can be given additional processing flags, amongst them `i` for the purpose at hand. So just replace your pattern to `'/Desi Indian/i'` and you should match the file names regardless of their cases.

You may want to read a bit about those flags, or modifiers how they are called: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Great! I added the URL of the documentation so that you can read a bit deeper into that stuff. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 '/YOURSEARCHSTRING/i'
```

The `i` pattern modifier will match both upper and lower case word